# MBP boots only through single user mode

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, startup

After using my MBP and shutting it down as usual, it fails to boot.

If no keys are pressed during booting ( normal boot ), a progress bar will appear on the bottom side of the screen, moves slowly, and shut downs after 4-5 seconds.

Booting with verbose mode enabled ( holding Cmd+V while booting ) gives the following logs before it dies :

```
hfs: mounted SSD on device root_device
com.apple.launchd                1       com.apple.launchd
com.apple.launchd                1       com.apple.launchd
 ***
com.apple.launchd
** /dev/rdisk0s2 (NO WRITE)
** Root file system
Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-226.1.1).
** /dev/rdisk0s2
** Root file system
Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-226.1.1).
** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
The volume name is SSD
** Checking extents overflow file.
** Checking catalog file.
AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::checkStatus - received Status Packet, Payload 2: device was reinitialized
   Invalid index key
(4, 20220)
   Invalid node structure
(4, 38065)
** The volume SSD could not be verified completely.
Kext loading is now disabled.
Kext unloading is now disabled.
Kext autounloading is now disabled.
com.apple.launchd                1       com.apple.launchd
n  7 22:08:18 2014    
com.apple.launchd                1       com.apple.launchd.System


continuing
hfs: unmount initiated on SSD on device unknown device
done
CPU halted.
syncing disks... Killing all processes AirPort: Link Down on . Reason 8 ( Disassociated because station le --- ...something
<mbp dies at this point, screen off>
```

I tried booting to Recovery mode and run disk utility. Verifying the system drive gives no errors. Pressing the Repair button gives an error message ( of which I forgot ). Pressing Verify button after this gives another error message.

Booting into single user mode ( holding Cmd+S while booting ) works, I tried running fsck, and it fails; ends with CPU halt message and it shuts down.
However if I mounted / with read and write access, then exit the terminal and proceed to boot, **it boots successfully.**

Running Verify Disk Permission using Disk Utility on the system partition (SSD) gives the following logs :

```
Open error 5: “Input/output error” on System/Library/ScreenReader/BrailleTables/Duxbury.brailletable/Contents/Resources/vi.lproj
Open error 5: “Input/output error” on System/Library/ScreenReader/BrailleTables/Duxbury.brailletable/Contents/Resources/vi.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
Open error 5: “Input/output error” on System/Library/ScreenReader/BrailleTables/Duxbury.brailletable/Contents/Resources/zh_CN.lproj
Open error 5: “Input/output error” on System/Library/ScreenReader/BrailleTables/Duxbury.brailletable/Contents/Resources/zh_CN.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
Open error 5: “Input/output error” on System/Library/ScreenReader/BrailleTables/Duxbury.brailletable/Contents/Resources/zh_TW.lproj
Open error 5: “Input/output error” on System/Library/ScreenReader/BrailleTables/Duxbury.brailletable/Contents/Resources/zh_TW.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
Open error 5: “Input/output error” on usr/standalone/i386/Firmware.scap
Open error 5: “Input/output error” on System/Library/ScreenReader/BrailleTables/Duxbury.brailletable/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
Open error 5: “Input/output error” on System/Library/ScreenReader/BrailleTables/Duxbury.brailletable/Contents/Resources/unimap.txt
Open error 5: “Input/output error” on System/Library/ScreenReader/BrailleTables/Duxbury.brailletable/Contents/Resources/uniyue.txt
Open error 5: “Input/output error” on System/Library/ScreenReader/BrailleTables/Duxbury.brailletable/Contents/Resources/zhmpcb.btb
Open error 5: “Input/output error” on System/Library/ScreenReader/BrailleTables/Duxbury.brailletable/Contents/Resources/zhmpcp.btb
Open error 5: “Input/output error” on System/Library/ScreenReader/BrailleTables/Duxbury.brailletable/Contents/Resources/zhyjcb.btb
Open error 5: “Input/output error” on System/Library/ScreenReader/BrailleTables/Duxbury.brailletable/Contents/Resources/zhyjcp.btb
Open error 5: “Input/output error” on System/Library/ScreenReader/BrailleTables/Duxbury.brailletable/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
Open error 5: “Input/output error” on usr/standalone/i386/boot.efi
Open error 5: “Input/output error” on usr/standalone/i386/tmbootpicker.efi

Permissions verification complete
```

Currently, I have to boot to Single user mode and mount / with read and write access manually to boot to OSX successfully. I have no idea what caused this and the solution to this problem. Please help me on solving this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issue solved; no physical errors.
These are what I did:

First I analyzed where the error occurred :

```
...
** Checking catalog file.
Invalid index key
(4, 20220)
Invalid node structure
(4, 38065)
The volume SSD could not be verified completely.
...
```

`fsck` stops while scanning catalog files. Let's try reading `fsck_hfs` user manual by executing `man fsck_hfs` for clues.

```
...
-R flags Rebuilds the requested btree.  The following flags are supported:
     a       Attribute btree
     c       Catalog btree
     e       Extents overflow btree
...
```

Let's try rebuilding catalog btree then. `fsck_hfs -Rc /dev/rdisk0s2`

Results: `fsck` does not stop at catalog file check anymore, and the `Invalid index key` error disappeared, revealing more errors ( clues! ).

```
** Checking extents overflow file.
Incorrect block count for file Cache.db-wal
(It should be 114 instead of 119)
** Checking catalog file.
Missing thread record (id = 30291961)
Incorrect number of thread records
Incorrect number of thread records
** Checking multi-linked files
** Checking catalog hierarchy.
Invalid directory item count
(It should be 221 instead of 244)
Invalid volume file count
(It should be 1318081 instead of 1318117)
** Checking extended attributes file.
Invalid node structure
The volume SSD could not be verified completely.
```

`fsck` now stops when checking extended attributes file. Let's try rebuilding the attributes btree with `fsck -Ra /dev/rdisk0s2`.

Result(s): All errors, except `Invalid node structure` disappeared after the first repair attempt. It shows several invalid nodes, then attempts the second repair, and rechecks. It still shows some invalid nodes, but even less then before.

However the `fsck` stops with a message saying that it stops making repair attempts after 3 check failures. I ran `fsck -Ra /dev/rdisk0s2` again. It attempts to repair again, then rechecks. No invalid node structure error shows up!

It now makes `Invalid volume free blocks count`, `Invalid volume file count`, and `Invalid volume directory count` errors, but it doesn't stop yet!

After yet another attempt of repair, `fsck` finished without any errors.

Shut down. Boot normally without entering single user mode. And it works!
Problem solved by running `fsck` several times, rebuilding catalog btree, and attribute btree several times.

Comment: Note: I also ran `fsck_hfs` with S parameter to scan for bad blocks **before doing any of above**. I proceeded to investigate the issue because there were no bad blocks(no physical failure/error). Doing any of the above with bad blocks... might be bad.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a  sector fault on your SSD, maybe OSX know this and refuse to boot regularly.
Try to boot a Linux liveDVD and check for bad sectors (from its terminal):

```
sudo badblocks -v /dev/YourSSD
```

Answer (score 0):

At this point, you will want to boot to single user mode (or target mode) and copy off any files that are not backed up.

At that point, boot to Recovery HD and attempt to erase the Macintosh HD so that you can clean up the filesystem.

If you have an external drive to boot, that would be better as you could then repartition the entire SSD and then attempt Internet Recovery or another re-install of the OS. If you can't repair the SSD using software, then it will need a hardware swap of the drive or a repair of the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, only way to boot was SUM then mount -uw then exit and OSX would boot. Tried to mount as write via recovery partition and TechTool Pro eDrive and failed at every turn. I bought disk warrior and ran it off my TTP edrive USB, BINGO it fixed it !!!!

Below is the errors, I didn't check the read more first unfortunately

• 1 file had a duplicate ID that was repaired.!
!
• 17 files had a directory entry with an incorrect text encoding value that was repaired.!
!
• 1 folder had a custom icon that was found to be damaged.!
!
• 2 folders had a directory entry with an incorrect custom icon flag that was repaired.!
!
• 3 folders had a directory entry with an incorrect text encoding value that was repaired.!    !
• Incorrect values in the Volume Information were repaired.!
!
• Critical values in the Volume Information were incorrect and were repaired.!