# OSX Partition won't mount. Permissions seem wrong

Tags: macos, startup, permission, mount

OS X was spinning and spinning when trying to shutdown so I held down the the <kbd>⌽ Power</kbd> button to force shutdown.

Current Situation:

1. I cannot boot to OS X directly, I first have to boot to single user mode and manually mount the OS X partition (`/sbin/mount -uw /`) then reboot and it works.
2. Folder permissions on the Windows side are all screwy, even as admin can't save file to desktop etc.
3. I remote to desktop (XP) via Citrix and when I try to copy folder to OS X from the Citrix XP desktop (OS X drive appears in Windows) it will create the folder then say it cannot write to it. A check in OS X  shows the folder is created as read-only for everyone.

2(*) and 3 may be unrelated and require an alternate thread (happy to create such) but I have them here for completeness.

Possible Causes:

1. My computer was slow to sleep so I ran the following commands in Terminal based on an [article about Mavericks issues](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2013/10/mavericks-issues-and-fixes/#slideid-23467) and then I repaired permissions.

   ```
   sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.coreservices.appleevents ExitTimeOut -int 1

   sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.securityd ExitTimeOut -int 1

   sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder ExitTimeOut -int 1

   sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.diskarbitrationd ExitTimeOut -int 1

   sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.coreservices.appleid.authentication ExitTimeOut -int 1
   ```
2. Recent upgrade to Windows 8.1

What I have tried:

1. Disk Utility from OS X, recovery partition and TechTool edrive (10.9 compatible version). Results:

   > Incorrect number of threads but cannot fix.

   Repairing permissions just has a problem with one printer.
2. Techtool Pro (refuses to do a volume rebuild)
3. `fsck`

*) Sometimes I can get the OS X to mount in these programs and sometimes not.

Is there a permissions or partition table issue or something else? Does anyone know how to reverse the command line settings back to their original values?

**My setup:**
MacBook Pro 2011 17" (GPU fail seems imminent)
Bootcamp with OS X 10.9 and Win 8.1
MacDrive (on Windows side)
Parallels 8

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed to fix but I did have to pay some money.

I ran Disk Warrior from my TechTool Pro drive and it was fixed.
Below is the information that it returned.

• 1 file had a duplicate ID that was repaired.!
!
• 17 files had a directory entry with an incorrect text encoding value that was repaired.!
!
• 1 folder had a custom icon that was found to be damaged.!
!
• 2 folders had a directory entry with an incorrect custom icon flag that was repaired.!
!
• 3 folders had a directory entry with an incorrect text encoding value that was repaired.!   !
• Incorrect values in the Volume Information were repaired.!
!
• Critical values in the Volume Information were incorrect and were repaired.!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to [reinstall OS X from the recovery partition](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13871). If you don't erase the target volume from Disk Utility first, the Reinstall OS X option installs a new copy of OS X over the current installation. It should keep user files and settings in place, so it's not absolutely necessary to even have a backup. It fixed an issue I had where I was not able to start up in OS X.

If you don't already have backups, you can [use Disk Utility to save a disk image to an external drive](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1553) or [copy files to an external drive in single user mode](https://superuser.com/a/176546/69039).

I don't think it would help, but you can revert the changes to the launchd plists by running these commands in single user mode:

```
sudo defaults delete /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.coreservices.appleevents ExitTimeOut
sudo defaults delete /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.securityd ExitTimeOut
sudo defaults delete /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder ExitTimeOut
sudo defaults delete /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.diskarbitrationd ExitTimeOut
sudo defaults delete /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.coreservices.appleid.authentication ExitTimeOut
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately the disk mounts as read only when booting from TTP and recovery partition.... I tried to get it mount write but have failed. Only seems to mount Write when Single User Mode using mount -uw... This seems a similar issue http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116432/mbp-boots-only-through-single-user-mode